# How to control different JWTs if I have many valid public keys corresponding each token?

Tags: spring-security, jwt, public-key

I am using spring security, and I created a JWT checker. It checks only expiration time so far.

The problem is I expose two different apis, and the callers are also using different public/private keys to generate the jwt(s) I control, which means that I have two different public keys to be able to check the JWTs corresponding to them.

What would be the best way to keep only one function that checks tokens but which also switchs between public keys ?

example :

```
public class JwtControlValid {

   @Value("${public.key.A}") // from application.properties
   private String pubKeyA;

   @Value("${public.key.B}")
   private String pubKeyB;

   private RSAPublicKey getPubKey() {
     
       try {
         
         
         KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");

        //  if(caller A)
        X509EncodedKeySpec keySpecX509 = new X509EncodedKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(pubKeyA));

        //  if (caller B)
        X509EncodedKeySpec keySpecX509 = new X509EncodedKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(pubKeyB));


        RSAPublicKey pubKey = (RSAPublicKey) kf.generatePublic(keySpecX509);
          
        return pubKey;
        
       }catch ...
```

and another function that uses the first one to say if true or false :

```
public boolean isJwtValid(String jwt) {
    try {

        Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(getPublicKey()).parseClaimsJws(jwt);
        return true;

    } catch ....


    return false;
```

Both public keys are `RSA public keys`

Is there a clean way to switch between public keys depending on the jwt that I receive ?

Comment: usually the key Id `kid` claim is used for that. Every key is assiated with a key Id and the token has a claim with the right Id.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is I expose two different apis, and the callers are also using different public/private keys to generate the jwt(s) I control, which means that I have two different public keys to be able to check the JWTs corresponding to them.

Yes this is a problem and is not a standard. Having public keys for each client scales bad, and is in general not supported.

Spring out of the box supports [trusting single asymmetric key](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-decoder-public-key-builder) but not multiple because this is not a standard and i do not recommend this approach.

If you want to support multiple keys you should instead be using `JWKs` which are a number of keys exposed by the issuing service.

What this basically means that the issuer (the server/service) that issues your tokens, has an endpoint, which all resource servers can fetch the public keys needed to verify tokens.

Advantages is that you can rotate keys, you can check against multiple JWKs, it is scalable and secure etc.

**If you still want to go down your path which i highly do not recommend** then you can for example implement two [`JwtAuthenticationProvider`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/resource/authentication/JwtAuthenticationProvider.html) using its interface.

The you can resolve which one to use by implementing a [`AuthenticationManagerResolver`](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authenticationmanagerresolver).

I would highly recommend you read about the entire [JWT flow in the spring security official docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-architecture) and use `Nimbus` which comes included in spring security instead of `JJwt` which is just an extra not needed dependency.

**I just want to include, writing custom security is never good, and all it takes is one bug in your custom security code and your entire security might be useless. Thats why there are standards, RFC, and established flows. To avoid custom security solutions.**